# Why is the Euler-Lagrange equation this in generalised coordinates?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, textbook-erratum

I'm a chemist, first off, and I'm trying to self teach myself some graduate statistical mechanics from "Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Simulation" by David Chandler. The first chapter is on classical mechanics and I'm confused about the form of the Euler-Lagrange equation given in generalised coordinates, specifically where the factor of a half goes? In this $N$ refers to $N$ particles meaning $3N$ generalised coordinates required to describe them.

[[image: Euler Lagrange Equation In Generalised Coordinates1]

So I understand the form of the Lagrangian itself and the components of the mass metric tensor but the problem I have is when it's substituted into the EL equation. Why is there not a factor of a half in front of the second term when the derivative with respect to $q_{\gamma}$ is taken?

I understand why the factor of half and one summation is removed from the first term when the derivative with respect to $\dot{q_{\gamma}}$ is taken but not in the second term.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. There should be a factor of 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

OP is right. A half is missing in the second term on the LHS of eq. (1.4.19).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was driving myself crazy trying to find that factor of a half.